# Como sacar el Menor y mayor en un For Java

Tags: java

estoy comenzando en la programacion y quisiera saber como puedo sacar las cantidades mayores y menores de un ciclo for de n elementos, pero que ademas me aparezca la inicial que se pide, es decir que imprima el mayor es: Edad: 45 Inicial: b

```
public class Arrays {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Scanner cantidades = new Scanner(System.in);

        int dato, edad,mayor=0,menor=0;
        char nombre;

        System.out.println("Cuantos datos desea");
        dato = cantidades.nextInt();

        for(int i=0;i<dato;i++){

            System.out.println("Digite la inicial de su nombre");
            nombre = cantidades.next().charAt(0);

            System.out.println("Edad");
            edad = cantidades.nextInt();


            if(edad>mayor){
                mayor = edad;
            }

        }
         System.out.println("El mayor es: "+mayor);
         System.out.println("El menor es: ");

    }

}
```

gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una de las formas es teniendo un valor mínimo en la variable mayor y tener un valor máximo en la variable menor.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Arrays {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Scanner cantidades = new Scanner(System.in);

        int dato, edad, mayor = Integer.MIN_VALUE, menor = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        char nombre = '-', nombreMayor = '-', nombreMenor = '-';

        System.out.println("Cuantos datos desea");
        dato = cantidades.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < dato; i++) {

            System.out.println("Digite la inicial de su nombre");
            nombre = cantidades.next().charAt(0);

            System.out.println("Edad");
            edad = cantidades.nextInt();

            if (edad > mayor) {
                mayor = edad;
                nombreMayor = nombre;
            }

            if (edad < menor) {
                menor = edad;
                nombreMenor = nombre;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("El mayor es: " + "Edad: " + mayor + " Inicial: " + nombreMayor);
        System.out.println("El menor es: " + "Edad: " + menor + " Inicial: " + nombreMenor);

    }

}
```

Comment: Esta seria una solución más apropiada que la otra.

Answer (score 0):

lo estas haciendo bien, ya tienes como sacar el mayor. para el menor es exactamente lo mismo.
para la inicial correspondiente al mayor y menor solo tienes que agregar una variable para la inicial mayor y la menor:

```
...
//actualiza el numero mayor y su incial correspondiente
if(edad>mayor){
  mayor = edad;
  inicialMayor = nombre;
}
//actualiza el numero menor y su incial correspondiente
if(edad<menor){
  menor= edad;
  inicialMenor = nombre;
}
...
```

no olvides declarar las variables inicialMayor y inicialMenor:

```
int dato, edad,mayor=0,menor=0;
char nombre, inicialMayor, inicialMenor;
```